# Join two tables and display the details

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table.
1st table:
Table Name: User

```
-id
-name
```

2nd table:
Table Name: Record

```
-player1ID
-player2ID
-player3ID
-location
-time
```

I would like to display all records.
I use "`SELECT * FROM Record`"
However, I would like to display not the player ID, I want to display the name of the player. How can I write a SQL that can do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `INNER JOIN`.
The trick is to join the `User` table multiple times (under different aliases) because you need multiple values from it.

```
select u1.name as player1, u2.name as player2, u3.name as player3, r.location, r.time
from Record r
inner join User u1 on r.player1ID = u1.id
inner join User u2 on r.player2ID = u2.id
inner join User u3 on r.player3ID = u3.id
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you wish to have the 'record' table with names substituted in for the IDs?

In that case you can `JOIN` the `User` table to the `Record` table (read up about joins [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)):

```
SELECT u.name as player1, u2.name as player2, u3.name as player3,
       r.location, r.time
FROM Record r
JOIN User u  ON  u.id=player1ID
JOIN User u2 ON u2.id=player2ID
JOIN User u3 ON u3.id=player3ID
```

Answer (score 0):

select a.name, b.name, c.name, d.location, d.time from Record d, User a, User b, User c where d.player1Id=a.id && d.player2ID = b.id && d.player3ID = c.id;